# TempVars to save record ID for opening a subform

Tags: vba, forms, ms-access

I am currently getting "*Run-time error '-2146500594 (800f000e)': Method 'Form' of object'_SubForm' failed*" when I run the following code:

```
TempVars.Add "TempFlightID", Me![FlightsPlan_SubFrm].Form!Text48
```

I am working on a set of navigation buttons for a set of forms some with and some without subforms in MS-Access. The goal is to have it open the needed form and have it be in the same record in the parent form as on the form that the user is currently on, and if there is a subform the same record in the subform as well. If there is not a subform it should save the ID for the record and the next time the user opens a form with a subform it should open with that ID.

I think I have the parent form navigation functional using open arguments, but can't seem to get the subform to work as intended. I am attempting to accomplish this by saving the subform ID as a TempVars as below (objects renamed for clarity):

```
Private Sub OpenParentForm2Btn_Click()
IDref = Me.ID
TempVars.Add "TempID", Me![SubFrm_1].Form![SubFrm_1ID]
DoCmd.OpenForm "ParentForm2", , , , , , IDref
DoCmd.Close acForm, "ParentForm1"
End Sub
```

Then on the second subform:

```
Private Sub Form_Load()
If [TempVars]("TempID") > "" Then
Me.Recordset.FindFirst "ID=" & [TempVars]("TempID")
Else
DoCmd.GoToRecord , , acLast
End If
End Sub
```

and for completeness here is the working code on the second parent form:

```
Private Sub Form_Load()
If Me.OpenArgs > "" Then
Me.Recordset.FindFirst "ID=" & Me.OpenArgs
Else
DoCmd.GoToRecord , , acLast
End If
End Sub
```

Any help resolving the error or directing me to a different method to accomplish this than TempVars would be appreciated.

-Cameron

Comment: It seems to Compile fine, no errors pop up. I had not heard of Rubberduck before, downloading it now to check it out.

Comment: Not seeing any procedure with line `TempVars.Add "TempFlightID", Me![FlightsPlan_SubFrm].Form!Text48`.

Comment: @CameronBrinton  Its the code inspections you want to look at.

Comment: @June7 I renamed the objects in the full example sub as I thought it would increase clarity, it reads: TempVars.Add "TempID", Me![SubFrm_1].Form![SubFrm_1ID]

Comment: So Master/Child Links properties of subform container control are not useful for this situation?

Comment: @freeflow Rubberduck is giving me this error: The expression 'Me![FlightsPlan_SubFrm]' requires a default member access, but the type 'MyDatabase.ParentForm' does not have a suitable default member

Comment: @June7 I do have the subform linked to the ID key on the master/parent form so that the users can only cycle through the subform records associated with the master/parent form. However I don't know how this property could be exploited to link across subforms on different master/parent forms

Comment: Wait, think I just got an inkling of what you are doing. Why would there be multiple forms/subform(s) with same data sources? Why multiple "parent" forms?

Comment: @June7 The database is for planning and making logs of UAV operations on a small windows tablet we take into the field. I optimizing it for navigation on the small screen by dividing into multiple forms. The parent forms hold all the navigation buttons and info from the control source, operation name, etc. Some of the parent forms hold information that is unrelated, but several hold information that is linked such as the Flight Plan and Pre-Flight checklist which are both tied to the same flight ID and thus the user will need to be on the same flight when they switch to a different section.

Comment: So would use of Tab control reduce need to 'break up' parent form?

Comment: @June7 Huh, didn't know you could do that. It might be a solution I could live with. Looks like it would at least solve it for navigating between the related subforms. It might not keep the record they were on instead defaulting to the newest if the user navigated away to one of the unrelated forms and then back, but that shouldn't be a frequent occurrence so not a big deal.

Comment: I've never deployed TempVars but just did a test and adding .Value to end of reference worked: `Me![SubFrm_1].Form![SubFrm_1ID].Value`. Although not using it gave me a different error message.

Comment: Pages of a Tab control can hold basically any type of control, even subform containers.

Comment: No luck adding .Value. I think that was part of the problem, but I have something else going on. I can't seem to get a successful reference to anything in the subform, been trying to just set the source of a text box to anything in the subform and failing.

Comment: Why would you need to change source of textbox - do you mean ControlSource? Cannot replicate issue so cannot advise solution.

Comment: @June7 Yes the control source, my thought was to check if I was referencing the ID in the child form correctly by creating  a simple text box to display it or the value of some other control in the parent form. So I set the control source of the text box to be **=Me![SubFrm_1].Form![SubFrm_1ID].Value** and when that didn't work substituted in a couple of other controls to no avail. going through to see if I have a typo somewhere, but would have thought that would have been flagged when I compiled.

Comment: Can't use Me in ControlSource - it is a VBA feature.